# if-then in kotlin's @JsonProperty?

Tags: json, kotlin

I want to do something weird... :)

I have a json file that will have either 1 key name OR another keyname. I want to detect which one is actually there, and assign to kotlin variable in class. Only one OR the other will be there. So,

```
  data class CED(
   @JsonProperty("rev_env")
   var revision: Any? = null,
   @JsonProperty("rev")
   var revision: Any? = null,
```

.
.
.

So, either rev_env OR rev will be in the json file, but whichever is there, their mapping always goes to "revision".

Any way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@JsonAlias`.
For example:

```
data class A(
    @JsonAlias(value = ["rev", "rev_env"])
    val rev: Any? = null
```

)

Comment: I'm getting this now: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type `com.ge.sdm.mla.turbineconfig.conpar.ConParDTO$ComponentEnvelopeDTO`: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for com.ge.sdm.mla.turbineconfig.conpar.ConParDTO$ComponentEnvelopeDTO, annotations: [null]] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-parameter constructor annotated as Creator

Comment: Although I used var revision rather than val rev ...